# Batch file: How to read and output a line from text file with special characters

Tags: batch-file

I've got a batch file that reads lines from a text file and if they don't contain a string writes them out to another text file.
However, I am getting an error:

My code:

```
:Read
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion enableextensions
for /F "tokens=* delims=" %%i in ('findstr /n $ C:\Preview.txt') do set "str1=%%i"

echo !str1!

if not x%str1:"^/DATA^/"=%==x%str1% echo "!str1!" >> !_MERGEREPORTNAME! 2>&1

endlocal
```

I'm guessing it works fine up to the echo !str1! since it does echo the string i.e.

> 4:merge, edit:
>   $/DEVSRC/2013/REL/13-REL-10/Databases/Product_Catalog/DATA/StateS
>   cripts/RatePlan-WI-1/MLQ-StateScripts/s_Coverage.sql;C981~C981 ->
>   $/DEVSRC/2013/
>   PCH/13-REL-10-P2/Databases/Product_Catalog/DATA/StateScripts/RatePlan-WI-1/MLQ-S tateScripts/s_Coverage.sql;C313

but then it errors out with "edit: was unexpected at this time."

Any help ideas would be appreciated.

EDIT: here is my text file which changes all of the time

```
Conflict (merge, edit): $/DEVSRC/2013/REL/13-REL-10/Databases/Product_Catalog/StateScripts/RatePlan-WI-1/MLQAgent-StateScripts/s_Coverage.sql;C981~C981 -> $/DEVSRC/2013/PCH/13-REL-10-P2/Databases/Product_Catalog/StateScripts/RatePlan-WI-1/MLQAgent-StateScripts/s_Coverage.sql;C655
merge, edit: $/DEVSRC/2013/REL/13-REL-10/Databases/Product_Catalog/DATA/BaseScripts/b_App_Fabric_Cache_Reset.sql;C981~C981 -> $/DEVSRC/2013/PCH/13-REL-10-P2/Databases/Product_Catalog/DATA/BaseScripts/b_App_Fabric_Cache_Reset.sql;C313
merge, edit: $/DEVSRC/2013/REL/13-REL-10/Databases/Product_Catalog/DATA/BaseScripts/b_Document_Type.sql;C981~C981 -> $/DEVSRC/2013/PCH/13-REL-10-P2/Databases/Product_Catalog/DATA/BaseScripts/b_Document_Type.sql;C313
merge, edit: $/DEVSRC/2013/REL/13-REL-10/Databases/Product_Catalog/StateScripts/RatePlan-WI-1/MLQ-StateScripts/s_Coverage.sql;C981~C981 -> $/DEVSRC/2013/PCH/13-REL-10-P2/Databases/Product_Catalog/StateScripts/RatePlan-WI-1/MLQ-StateScripts/s_Coverage.sql;C313
```

Can't answer my own question yet, but this worked:

this worked. thanks to foxidrive for the right direction to look

```
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion enableextensions
for /F "tokens=* delims=" %%i in ('findstr /n $ C:\Preview.txt') do (set "str1=%%i"
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

echo !str1!

set "search=/DATA/"

echo "!str1!"|find "!search!">nul && (
echo found
echo "/DATA/ files excluded" >> !_MERGEREPORTNAME! 2>&1
)||(
echo not FOUND
echo "!str1!" >> !_MERGEREPORTNAME! 2>&1
)

)
endlocal
```

Answer (score 1):

This will echo the line if it doesn't /DATA/

```
echo "!str1!"|find "/DATA/">nul || echo "!str1!" >> !_MERGEREPORTNAME! 2>&1
```

Comment: Thanks, this one kind of works, I don't get any errors but it echos to the file all of the lines whether they contain /DATA/ or not.

Comment: I see that you changed the code and put it within a loop.  You will need the delayed expansion that I changed in the first variable in the code above.  Try it again.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest

```
if not "x%str1:/DATA/=%"=="x%str1%" echo "!str1!" >> !_MERGEREPORTNAME! 2>&1
```